# Forma arcaica de "os miro"

Tags: español-medieval

Estoy escribiendo algo con un español arcaico, pero no sé la respuesta para alguna situación. En el español arcaico, yo sé que se junta el pronombre con el verbo conjugado. Por ejemplo, en vez de decir "les preguntó", la forma arcaica sería "preguntoles", y no hay acento en la o porque la palabra termina con -s y el estrés está en la penúltima sílaba. Así que el estrés ya está en la -o, como en la forma original. Quisiese combinar las palabras de la frase "os miro". Por el motivo de que la palabra "miro" termina con -o y la palabra "os" empieza con o-, creo que la forma arcaica correcta es "miros", porque no puede ser "míroos". Pero no estoy seguro si mi forma de pensar está correcta o no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sería **míroos**, porque la primera sílaba es la acentuada sin el tilde y la *s* final pondría el acento en la penúltima sílaba.  No hay motivo por la reducción de las dos oes como pasa en una palabra como *decimoctavo*.

Ten en cuenta que el tilde viene de una ortografía más moderna, y en el castellano verdaderamente arcaico, aparecería como **miroos** o incluso **miro os**.  Sería posible, aunque no creo recordar haberlo visto, que se reduzca a *miros* (era frecuente ver los pronombres *le/lo* reducidos a *l*), pero si el resto de lo que escribes tiene una ortografía, sería muy recomendable usar la variante gráfica moderna de **míroos**.

Y **ojo**: la enclisis no se usaba siempre. Existían reglas para su (no) uso. Por ejemplo, se decía *míroos* pero *no(n) míroos* es inválido, se tenía que decir *no(n) os miro*. Igualmente *sabéis que míroos* no se decía, sino *sabéis que os miro*, pero tras un *porque* (o *ca*, que era más común) sí se usaba: *sé que estáis porque/ca míroos*. Las reglas cambiaron varias veces con el paso de tiempo.

Comment: hmm.. no seria mejor cambiar a miroles y mirote ?

Comment: @Mike no. *Os* (aún más antiguamente *vos*) es el pronombre átono para los pronombres tónicos *vos* y *vosotros*. El uso de *te* en lugar de *os* para el voseo es bastante moderno, y el empleo de *les* (u otras formas de la 3.ª persona) podría.ser un uso indebido del formal que no existía tal como existe hoy (*vos* podría ser singular o plural, sin distinción de formalidad en el plural y con variaciones en formalidad según época entre los también pronombres de 2.ª persona *tú* y *él*.

Comment: @guifa también iba decir eso

Answer (score 1):

Por complementar la respuesta de guifa, decir que solo he encontrado un caso de "míroos" en el CORDE:

> *Ya las retamas se ven
>
>   del portal entre esos tejos. 
>
>   Míroos desde lejos. 
>
>   portal de Belén, 
>
>   míroos desde lejos, 
>
>   parecéisme bien.*
>
> Luis de Góngora y Argote, "Letrilla", 1615 (España).

Parece que "míroos" no era una forma común, pero el hecho de que un grande como Góngora la usara da validez a esta forma.

Comment: Míroos era poco común, pero *véoos* sale con cinco resultados más antiguos (y *véovos* con ocho).  No obstante, en CORDE actualizan un poco la ortografía por lo que sin poder ver los documentos originales no sabremos la ortografía antigua.

Comment: (y con *veo os* y *veo vos* salen algunos de más, pero no todos los resultados son del verbo *ver(v)os*, algunos son *ver* + otro verbo con *(v)os*)